# Swap two entries in a Binding Source

Tags: c#, bindingsource

I have a binding source which serves as a data source for a data grid.After binding the binding source I am trying to  swap the two rows of the binding source.

```
 object currentRow = dashBoardBindingSource[index];
                    object aboveRow = dashBoardBindingSource[index - 1];
                    dashBoardBindingSource[index] = aboveRow;
                    dashBoardBindingSource[index - 1] = currentRow;
```

The above code gives me an exception as follows

```
Cannot set an object into this list.
```

I am using following code to bind the data to the binding source

```
OnlineOutageReport[] outageReports;
dashBoardBindingSource = new BindingSource();
            dashBoardBindingSource.DataSource = ToDataTable<OnlineOutageReport>(outageReports);


private static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(
        prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);

        }
        object[] values = new object[props.Count];
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
            }
            table.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        return table;
    }
```

Anybody have an idea.
Thanks

Comment: dashBoardBindingSource.DataSource = outageReports; works fine.But after I put dashBoardBindingSource.Sort=sortOrder; It is not working.After I do that it works fine

Comment: when dashBoardBindingSource.DataSource = outageReports; its hows the data.But it want sort the binding source based on my criteria. Thats why I convert it in to a data table. After I convert it and assigned it the sorting works fine

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I move a bindingSource from one row of a DataGridView to another.

```
            int index = this.KeyDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index;

            this.KeyDataGridView.ClearSelection();
            if (index == this.KeyDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                return;//can go down
            }
            var tempKey = this.keysBindingSource[index];
            this.keysBindingSource.RemoveAt(index);
            this.keysBindingSource.Insert(index + 1, tempKey);
```

It may just require you to use dataSource.Insert(index) instead